# Every immersed contractible loop has a neighbourhood with $H^2=0$.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, differential-topology

Let $c: S^1 \to M$ be a contractible smooth loop. Is it true that $c(S^1)$ has a neighbourhood $U$ such that $H^2(U;\mathbb{R})=0$?

If $c$ is an embedding this is clear by tubular neighbourhood, but I don't know how to tackle the general case. I suspect the result to be true without the contractibility assumption, but I only need it in this case for my purposes.

Comment: Try approximating $c$ by a smooth map, then using a transversality result to reduce to the case of an embedding.

Comment: @anomaly: $c$ should be smooth to begin with or else the existence of space-filling curves shows the answer is "no". Take a continuous curve visiting every point on the 2-torus, then concatenate it with its inverse, in case it was not contractible to start with.

Comment: @MikeF: Good point. I missed the "smooth" note in the post.

Comment: is $M$ a manifold of arbitrary dimension?